# How to acces/find RDF files from retailers

Tags: rdf, n-triples

I need to make a shopbot using RDF files.
I've looked on what are rdf files, and how are they used, and that is kinda clear, that they are a standard model that follows an ontology to display a catalog of items/data.
But I cant find where, or how, to access an online RDF catalog of a retailer(any retailer). There might be something that I am missing, or I have the wrong idea.

Any help or advice would be greatly apreciated. Thanks a lot!

I've stumbled upon Turtle, N -Triples, N-Quads. But those seem to be a way to load the resources, not access them. Found rdf ontologies, but again, no "catalogues" of items.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I guess your assumption that any shop retailer will provide their product catalog as RDF is wrong - why should any shop do this? I mean, they mostly won't expose their database not even in any structured format because of why should they? Indeed, their might be some access to it on request, but I don't see any need to publish data for free without any clear use. Other than that, you should have a look at the good relations dataset around - those are the most promising datasets for you